# INSUFFICENT_STORAGE_MEMORY message while install 50 mb apk in emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator

when I am install `50 mb apk` in my emulator with command line, I got error like ::
[image]

**So what thing i have to this to increase memory?**

**UPDATE :**
i have got another error like :: 
[image]

**UPDATE : i have got another error like ::**

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

you need to increase virtual memory of emulator

**How to increase virtual memory of emulator**

```
\\emulator -avd "Emulator Name" -partition-size 500
```

after then try to install your apk

Comment: perfect solution +1
D:\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\emulator -avd "Emulator Name" -partition-size 500
Then open second command prompt write your installation command
D:\Android\android-sdk-windows\platform-tools

Comment: when i run this command i got an error , i think it is emulator command error

Comment: cd D:\Android\android-sdk-windows\tools\emulator and press enter

Comment: then emulator -avd "Emulator Name" -partition-size 500

Comment: write your avd name rather than id, ie not "5556", the name you created in AVD "sampleavd", in your case remove 5556:

Comment: just write "2.2" instead of "5556:2.2"

Comment: first close all emulator and try this, dear

Comment: where does one type `\\emulator -avd "Emulator Name" -partition-size 500`? I am using eclipse and AVD get launched from eclipse.

Comment: Ah `cmd.exe` ... I had to `cd c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\tools` then run `emulator.exe -avd "red_virt" -p artition-size 500` them my app install without error. THANKS!