# invalid command-line parameter: partition-size

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I got these errors many times, when I was running my project. Any idea for solving this problem?

```
[2011-07-25 13:07:19 - Test1] ------------------------------
[2011-07-25 13:07:19 - Test1] Android Launch!
[2011-07-25 13:07:19 - Test1] adb is running normally.
[2011-07-25 13:07:19 - Test1] Performing com.horror.android.Test1Activity activity launch
[2011-07-25 13:07:20 - Test1] Automatic Target Mode: Unable to detect device compatibility. Please select a target device.
[2011-07-25 13:07:25 - Test1] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Eight'
[2011-07-25 13:07:26 - Emulator] invalid command-line parameter: partition-size.
[2011-07-25 13:07:26 - Emulator] Hint: use '@foo' to launch a virtual device named 'foo'.
[2011-07-25 13:07:26 - Emulator] please use -help for more information
```

Comment: what you wrote in command line?

Comment: I am trying to switch one activity to another activity via the button click.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think that your application might be large and your internal memory of your emulator is low, thats why happening so refer this [INSUFFICENT_STORAGE_MEMORY message while install 50 mb apk in emulator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743115/insufficent-storage-memory-message-while-install-50-mb-apk-in-emulator/6743176#6743176)

Comment: If the answer is helpful to you then you have to vote-up the answer.