# unable to install apk file on AVD Emulator

Tags: android

I have an apk file which have to install on AVD Emulator.
But it is showing outofspace dialog with message(app could not be viewed. Free up some space on your and try again).

I do uninstall some apps and free memory and install again the app after uninstalling it.
but again it is showing same alert msg.

Please tell what should i do...

Thanks..

Comment: see that 
[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835609/android-4-0-emulator-out-of-space-error/7847148#7847148][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835609/android-4-0-emulator-out-of-space-error/7847148#7847148

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First go to the command line,

```
>> android-sdk-windows\tools>
```

Then close your all of your current AVD. Then

```
emulator -avd Donut -partition-size 512
```

Comment: you are right but try this so you can increase actual size in mb.if you got any problem then ping me

Answer (score 1):

you need to increase virtual memory of emulator

**How to increase virtual memory of emulator**

```
\\emulator -avd "Emulator Name" -partition-size 500
```

after then try to install your apk

if any query about it then see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743115/insufficent-storage-memory-message-while-install-50-mb-apk-in-emulator/6743176#6743176)

Comment: C:\Users\ngahp5>emulator -avd GDcmd -partition-size 500
emulator: ERROR: the user data image is used by another emulator. aborting ......... when i use this in cmd it shows error like above

Answer (score 0):

When you create a AVD, give more memory to it, you can even edit the existing AVD and give more memory and try to install after that.

Comment: I have already give 60 mb , 100 mb and 1024 mb three times to make avd