# Android 4.0 emulator - out of space error

Tags: android, android-emulator

I get an Out of space error when i try to install my app on the android 4.0 emulator.
It gives me a message asking me to cleanup the space. When i go to internal storage I see 12 MB free which more that enough for my app.

To be safe, is there a way i can increase the Internal Storage of the Emulator

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Create an AVD (example: "android4") In Eclipse with the Android Virtual Device Manager

go to a terminal

***cd [android directory]/tools/***

linux terminal:      ***./emulator -avd android4 -partition-size 512 &***

windows :     ***emulator -avd android4 -partition-size 512***

Then install your app in this emulator

Answer (score 4):

append `-partition-size 512` to the emulator options

if it didn't work create a new Device

Comment: I too get the same error. I even tried increasing the SD card to 2GB without much success. @Avinash, did you find any solution to this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7837122/java-lang-outofmemoryerror-on-android-4-0-api-14

Comment: +1 for this sentence: "if it didn't work create a new Device". I found many solution but create a new device solve my problem. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

Also try increasing the heap size to something like 64MB. This solved the issue for me.

[image]