# java.lang.OutOfMemoryError on Android 4.0 (API 14)

Tags: android, api, tabs

I have an Android app that works well in the emulators for Android 2.2, 2.3.1 & 2.3.3. But when I test it out on Android 4.0, it gives this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo
…
…    
Caused by: java.view.InflateException
…
…
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
…
…
Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError
```

It occurs everytime I try to go the next activity! (I use a `TabActivity` which has 3 activities within it).

I am not sure what has changed in API 14. Please advice.

Comment: What is the value of the "Max VM application heap size" parameter in the AVD you use?

Comment: The value is 24.Do I have to increase that? If yes, what is an optimum increase?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. It works now. If you put your comment as an answer, I will be glad to accept it. :)

Comment: Posted. Glad to help :) Btw what value have you set?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Check the value of the "Max VM application heap size" parameter in the AVD you use. Android 3.x AVD uses by default 48 Mb, so it should be at least not less for Android 4.0.
I couldn't find the specification of Galaxy S II with heap size info included, but I suggest you to try 48 or 64 Mb.