# APK fails to install on Android 4.0 emulator

Tags: android-emulator

On all previous SDK-s apk is working fine. Tried to test on 4.0. Downloaded all last updates from eclipse. And what I get

...

```
[2011-10-28 11:39:34 - breath-trainer] Android Launch!
[2011-10-28 11:39:34 - breath-trainer] adb is running normally.
[2011-10-28 11:39:34 - breath-trainer] Performing com.breath.ui.activity.BreathTrainerActivity activity launch
[2011-10-28 11:39:37 - breath-trainer] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device '4.0_api_14_SUKA'
[2011-10-28 11:39:38 - breath-trainer] New emulator found: emulator-5554
[2011-10-28 11:39:38 - breath-trainer] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be launched...
[2011-10-28 11:40:30 - breath-trainer] HOME is up on device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-10-28 11:40:30 - breath-trainer] Uploading breath-trainer.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-10-28 11:40:31 - breath-trainer] Installing breath-trainer.apk...
[2011-10-28 11:40:56 - breath-trainer] Success!
[2011-10-28 11:40:56 - breath-trainer] Failed to install breath-trainer.apk on device 'emulator-5554': device not found
[2011-10-28 11:40:56 - breath-trainer] com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: device not found
[2011-10-28 11:40:56 - breath-trainer] Launch canceled!
```

Also in LogCat there are a lot of exceptions concerning StrictMode policy violation and smallest one:

```
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74): problem reading network stats
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74): java.lang.IllegalStateException: problem parsing line: null
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:313)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at com.android.server.NetworkManagementService.getNetworkStatsUidDetail(NetworkManagementService.java:1223)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.performPollLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:810)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfacesLocked(NetworkStatsService.java:721)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.updateIfaces(NetworkStatsService.java:699)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService.access$000(NetworkStatsService.java:128)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at com.android.server.net.NetworkStatsService$8.handleMessage(NetworkStatsService.java:1546)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:60)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74): Caused by: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /proc/net/xt_qtaguid/stats: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:406)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:78)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:42)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at com.android.internal.net.NetworkStatsFactory.readNetworkStatsDetail(NetworkStatsFactory.java:272)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     ... 9 more
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java:98)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     at libcore.io.IoBridge.open(IoBridge.java:390)
10-28 11:40:51.711: A/NetworkStats(74):     ... 12 more
```

Some ideas?

Comment: Sorry, when typing question, text is formated fine...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**'emulator-5554': device not found**

**Virtual Device '4.0_api_14_SUKA'**

2 Theorys:

1.- The emulator is an api 14 (Android 4.0) and the emulator is out of space:
Try this --> [Android 4.0 emulator - out of space error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7835609/android-4-0-emulator-out-of-space-error/7847148#7847148)

2.- Sometimes the connection between Eclipse and the emulator is lost. Close the emulator and reopen it.

Answer (score 2):

I had this problem. I can't properly explain why it happened, but I can tell you how I worked around it. When I got this message, the ICS emulator still appeared. My application was installed and could be launched by going to the applications and selecting it. The bigger issue for me was that logcat was no longer working. To get it working again for the running emulator, I do the following from the command line:
(assuming your environmental variables are set up)
1) enter "adb" 
2) enter "adb kill-server"
3) enter "adb start-server"
4) relaunch the application and target the running emulator

I hope that works for you as it did for me. I'd love it if someone could actually explain this problem properly. From the research I've done, it looks like it's related to Strict Mode or some kind of timeout. Someone else suggested that I update the timeout setting for adb in eclipse. This didn't work for me, but it might help someone else: Eclipse > Preferences > Android > DDMS - then set the ADB connection timeout to something higher than the time it takes for you system to start ICS.

Answer (score 0):

That is not the main problem, I run it on my device I got the same error, but the ICS runs :P