# how to install application with 80 mb size in emulator?

Tags: android

I have created  an application for samsung galaxy tab 10 inch,but i couldn't install it in emulator.showing in sufficient storage.Please help me for the same.

Comment: uninstall previous applications in emulator and try

Comment: yup. its working now.Do you know the maximum size of Android App.

Comment: Unless it is a fairly large game, an 80MB app is too big, and you are having some trouble with it...

Comment: did u increase your memory size?

Comment: It is a Quiz application.I have added some images,total size is around 50 mb and i have to add more.

Comment: but I believe android market wont accpet apps with size more than 50mb.

Comment: http://androidflip.com/google-android-app-increased-size-limit-market/ please go through the above link.. Extended upto 4gb

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you need to increase virtual memory of emulator

**How to increase virtual memory of emulator**

```
\\emulator -avd "Emulator Name" -partition-size 500
```

after then try to install your apk

if any doubt then see all comment of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743115/insufficent-storage-memory-message-while-install-50-mb-apk-in-emulator/6743176#6743176)