# Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE

Tags: android, adb, android-virtual-device, android-sdk-2.1

I get the error mentioned in the title when I run my app on the emulator.
While creating it, I had given a sufficient space.

How can you fix this?

My log file:

```
[2011-09-16 09:28:17 - Trivia] Performing nik.trivia.Splash activity launch
[2011-09-16 09:28:17 - Trivia] Automatic Target Mode: using existing emulator 'emulator-5554' running compatible AVD 'work'
[2011-09-16 09:28:17 - Trivia] Uploading Trivia.apk onto device 'emulator-5554'
[2011-09-16 09:30:54 - Trivia] Installing Trivia.apk...
[2011-09-16 09:30:56 - Trivia] Installation error: INSTALL_FAILED_INSUFFICIENT_STORAGE
[2011-09-16 09:30:56 - Trivia] Please check logcat output for more details.
[2011-09-16 09:30:56 - Trivia] Launch canceled!
```

Comment: Try this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2239330/how-to-increase-storage-for-android-emulator-install-failed-insufficient-storag

Answer (score 11, accepted):

you need to increase virtual memory of emulator

**How to increase virtual memory of emulator**

```
\\emulator -avd "Emulator Name" -partition-size 500
```

after then try to install your apk

if any doubt then see all comment of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743115/insufficent-storage-memory-message-while-install-50-mb-apk-in-emulator/6743176#6743176)

Comment: But what to do if it occur's for real device

Answer (score 6):

I work with the real device. Once I've got the same error. I had a lot of free space on SD card. So you may see this error if you don't have enough internal memory. You should delete some program from the device or move it on SD card. It solved my problem. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

This error can be caused by an application that has previously produced an error, and so it cannot be successfully terminated before installing the new version.

To fix the problem in this case, you can "Force stop" the application in the Application Manager of the device, or completely uninstall it.

Try running the app again and all should be well.

Answer (score 0):

If You are Installing the application to the Emulator then Some times it happend. I face same Problem and i have solve it by my way.

In my Problem, I have install the application in emulator that is larger as like more then 10mb. And After that, i am going to Install another Application to that emulator and got this error..

Sollution:

I have just Restart the Eclipse that will erace all unwanted Memory and will get refresh to install the new Application.

Note: Its only works for some Normal perpose. as like to get error after installing another application. . .etc. Otherwise follow CapDroid's answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When using a real device make sure you have enough space on your phone, i deleted some files on my device and it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

if you already have that app installed in ur mobile than  deleted the app itself by going to settings->Application selecting that app and uninstall it . if u face same problem than uninstall the other software to get more space in memory .

Answer (score 0):

```
You need to do two things after which this error will be resolved.

1. In your AndroidManifest.xml file add android:installLocation="preferExternal" within your manifest tag.

<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.packagename.appname"
android:versionCode="1"
android:versionName="1.0" 
android:installLocation="preferExternal">

2. More importantly, clear the cache data in your device. Goto settings -> storage -> click on cached data. This will clear the cache and free the space.

3. Reconnect your device, clean your project and again run it on the device. The project will now run on your device
```

Answer (score -1):

Just create a *New Emulator* then start that emulator and launch your Android app on that emulator by setting the target:

- Right click on the project and go to Run As
- Run configuration
- Go to target, click on always prompt to pick target
- Apply
- Run

There is a new screen in which you'll select the new emulator which you have created. Run that app.

Then there no such problem longer arises.