# mounting read and write permission to /system/app folder using adb shell commands

Tags: android

I want to push a .apk file to /system/app folder. For accomplishing this i tried these commands using adb shell commands
D:\mobile\android-sdk-windows\tools\adb -s emulator-5554 shell
mount
 mount -o remount,rw -t yaffs2 /dev/block/mtdblock0 /system 
 chmod 777 /system/app

Using these commands first i tried to mount r/w permisssion for /system/app folder and then i tried to push my apk file using `adb push Hello.apk /system/app command to /system/app

folder but could not able to do. I am getting error like this`failed to copy 'Hello.apk' to'/system/app/Hello.apk':out of memory"` 
 even though apk file size is 13kb.
Is anyone have idea wy i am getting such kind of error?
Advance thanks for any help.

Answer (score 2):

you need to increase virtual memory of emulator

to increase virtual memory of emulator

```
D:\mobile\android-sdk-windows\tools\adb emulator -avd "Emulator Name" -partition-size 500
```

after that do your additional task

if any doubt then see all comment of refer **[this question...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6743115/insufficent-storage-memory-message-while-install-50-mb-apk-in-emulator/6743176#6743176)**